# Convert disk with FreeBSD disklabel to MBR or GPT?

Tags: linux, partitioning, mbr, freebsd

I've got a disk that was once partitioned using only a FreeBSD disklabel.  The MBR is all 0.  The BSD partitions (as dumped by `gdisk` under Linux) are:

```
BSD partitions:
   1               16           2000000         0x0E
   2                0                 0         0x00
   3                0          78165360         0x00
   4          2000016          76165344         0x0E
   5                0                 0         0x00
   6                0                 0         0x00
   7                0                 0         0x00
   8                0                 0         0x00
```

The "transform" option of `gdisk` doesn't do anything because it wants to search inside a MBR partition for the BSD disklabel even though it finds it at boot.  I would just make a full disk MBR and try again but MBR wants to start at 2048 (or 63 in DOS mode) and I'm pretty sure the disklabel is in sector 1 (and you can see the partition starts at 16!)

(This disk has a ZFS log and L2ARC on it and the pool won't import without it... But I'm thinking I may just `dd` the log and the label blocks of the L2ARC up a bit so I can use a MBR/GPT compatible label)

Comment: The disk filesystem is, almost surely, ZFS. You do not make clear which (if any) package for handling ZFS you have installed. Any operation of the sort you mention will render the disk useless, unless you want to reformat it.

Comment: There is a reason why the installer calls this kind of formatting "dangerously dedicated".

Comment: @MariusMatutiae: Actually it worked fine because there's no persistent data in the L2ARC (the indexing is all in RAM so only the "ZFS label" matters for re-importing)